# Send several waiting messages after a waiting message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm asking for your help.
I'm trying to get a message sent waiting for a reply, then when the user answers within the time limit, it sends another message like this one.
I don't know if you understand me.
If you need more information, don't answer.

Sincerely.

My current code:

```js
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id && m.author.id !== bot.user.id

// CHOISIR LE NOM

            message.reply("S'il vous plaît choisissez un nom pour le tournoi.").then(r => r.delete(10000));
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
              max: 1,
              time: 10000
            }).then(collected => { 
              if(collected.first().content === "stop" || collected.first().content === "cancel"){
                return message.reply("Création du tournoi annulé.")
              }
              let tournamentname = collected.first().content;
              db.collection("tournois").findOneAndUpdate({"tournamentInformations.status": "active"}, {
                $set: {
                  "tournamentInformations.tournamentName": tournamentname
                  }}, {upsert: true}, function(err,doc) { if (err) { throw err; } });
              message.channel.send(":white_check_mark: | Vous avez défini le nom du tournoi à "+tournamentname);
                }).catch(err => {
                  console.log(err)
                })

// CHOISIR L'ORGANISATEUR

            message.reply("S'il vous plaît choisissez le nom de l'organisateur.").then(r => r.delete(10000));
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
              max: 1,
              time: 10000
            }).then(collected => { 
              if(collected.first().content === "stop" || collected.first().content === "cancel"){
                return message.reply("Création du tournoi annulé.")
              }
              let organisateur = collected.first().content;
              db.collection("tournois").findOneAndUpdate({"tournamentInformations.status": "active"}, {
                $set: {
                  "tournamentInformations.organizedBy": organisateur
                  }}, {upsert: true}, function(err,doc) { if (err) { throw err; } });
              message.channel.send(":white_check_mark: | Vous avez défini l'organisateur à "+organisateur);
                }).catch(err => {
                  console.log(err)
                })
```

Comment: Please include an [mcve] _in the question itself_, not as a link to another site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be in need of `.awaitMessages` and `.then` sequencing - I highly recommend googling your question prior to posting for at least 30 minutes, as well as actively searching the [official Discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) beforehand.

A simple example I can provide:

```js
message.channel.send('First question').then(async (first) => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { maxMatches: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time']}).then(async (collected) => {
                await first.delete()
                await collected.first().delete()
            }).then(async () => {
                message.channel.send('Question 2').then(async (second) => {
                    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { maxMatches: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time']}).then(async (collected) => {
                        await second.delete()
                        await collected.first().delete()
}).catch(collected => {
message.channel.send('Your answer timed out')
})

}).catch(collected => {
message.channel.send('Your answer timed out')
})
```

What this does (sloppily, as I copy and pasted this snippet and edited it from my own code, it might be missing tokens) is sends the first message `'First question'` and allows a 60 second response timeframe. If there is an answer, it deletes the question prompt as well as the answer (you can store the answer however you'd like,) then it proceeds to do the same for the second question, and so on and so forth. If the 60 second timeframe expires, it will end the sequence and tell the user they ran out of time.

Hope this helps, if it does, mark this as correct.

(P.S. if you are familiar with functions, all of this can be shoved into one to compact and simplify your code, I just provided you the example like this so as not to confuse you)

Comment: Thanks ! It works perfectly after that if you want to give it to me, I won't say no. :p

Comment: @Niromash If you aren't familiar with the usage, it would be somewhat detrimental to your code and learning, as you would run in to more problems. But now you know that it is possible to compact it, if you spend the time learning about functions etc.

Comment: I have already learned a little, I know some of them, simplistic certainly but I would like to see how it would make it work....

Comment: It is essentially the same, just without having to type the same code over and over.

Comment: Thank you, that's the purpose of a function x)